# How do I get the function that runs the function?

Tags: php

I'm using an error log function, and I want to include the function where the error occurred during the error log. Is there a way to write the function instead of writing the function every time?

```
<?php 

$a = null;

exampleFunction($a);

function exampleFunction($variable){

  if(is_null($variable)){

    errorLog("variable is null. ");

  }

}

function errorLog($text){

 error_log($text, 3, ".testLog");

}

?>
```

`__FUNCTION__` is not solution. If I use `__FUNCTION__` I get "errorLog". I want to know the name of the function that is running errorLog.

For example ;

```
function errorLog($text){

  error_log($text.' Function : '.$functionName, 3, ".testLog");

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use debug_backtrace to get a list of the function call stack:

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    bar();
}

function bar()
{
    echo debug_backtrace()[1]['function'];
}

foo();
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome. Thank you so much.